# No 'iOS team provisioning profile' appearing in developer portal (Itunes Connect) and Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, organizer

I have no more 'iOS team provisioning profile' appearing in Organizer or developer portal. I tried the following:

- connecting/disconnecting my device
- right click on my device in Organizer an then 'Add device to provisioning portal'
- create an team profile in developer portal but it seems that team profile is not in the list of profiles you can create => can't be created in the portal
- click on 'refresh' button at the bottom right of the 'Provisioning profiles' section of Organizer
- click on 'refresh' button at the bottom right of the 'Teams=>My Name' section of Organizer

What can I do ??...

Thanks !!

Comment: Which version of xcode are you using?

Comment: What is your role in the Dev portal?

Comment: karim: XCode 4.6.1. D80Buckeye : I have all the rights.

Comment: What happens when you click on Import?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution to my problem ! Here are the steps:

- go to the developer portal and display your devices list : https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action
- delete one of your iOS devices in this list of devices
- restart XCode
- open the organizer
- clicked on the device you just removed in the left column of the organizer
- click on "Add to Portal"
- and the magic happens: your iOS team profile appears and you are now able to launch and debug your app !

Thanks for your help guys !

PS : Shame on Apple for this kind of crazy things with crazy certificates, profiles, etc... which are always expiring and need to be renewed...with bugs overall... When will they simplify all these stuffs and propose a 2000 years validity of these things like on Android ???

Comment: Totally agree: shame on apple.  This process is a _mess_.